# While integrating PayUMoney payment gateway in Test mode error generate 'sorry some error occurred '

Tags: payu

When I use service_provider = **payu_paisa** then generates the error:

> ''sorry some error occurred '

without service_provider error into reponse

```
{
mihpayid: "403993715515010643",
mode: "CC",
status: "failure",
unmappedstatus: "failed",
key: "gtKFFx",
txnid: "a9de074d7d44e69e2ada",
amount: "232354.00",
cardCategory: "domestic",
discount: "0.00",
net_amount_debit: "0.00",
addedon: "2016-09-28 11:37:25",
productinfo: "shopping",
firstname: "sunil",
lastname: "",
address1: "surat",
address2: "surat",
city: "surat",
state: "gujarat",
country: "",
zipcode: "",
email: "sunil.1023p@gmail.com",
phone: "8978678798",
udf1: "",
udf2: "",
udf3: "",
udf4: "",
udf5: "",
udf6: "",
udf7: "",
udf8: "",
udf9: "",
udf10: "",
hash: "9725118686ef231af41264bdd12ab9f735abded558d3fbec5902d22ba5a2a6655af2f53bbc2938e7f320f928b6f119a003b856854e29d1fadbb4c59e421555cb",
field1: "",
field2: "",
field3: "",
field4: "",
field5: " !ERROR!-GV00010-Missing data typeError Code: GV00010",
field6: "",
field7: "",
field8: "failed in enrollment",
field9: " !ERROR!-GV00010-Missing data typeError Code: GV00010",
payment_source: "payu",
PG_TYPE: "HDFCPG",
bank_ref_num: "",
bankcode: "CC",
error: "E500",
error_Message: "Unknown Error Received from PG",
name_on_card: "sunil",
cardnum: "512345XXXXXX2346",
cardhash: "This field is no longer supported in postback params.",
issuing_bank: "HDFC",
card_type: "MAST"
}
```

Any can help me?

Comment: ERROR!-GV00010-Missing data typeError Code: GV00010

Comment: have you found answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

In new integration we do not need to send 
service_provider = payu_paisa

The documentation have been updated with the new parameter. You can check the documentation at 
https://developer.payubiz.in/documentation/Post-Request-%28Non-seamless%29/24

However, the development kits are yet to be updated.

Also,
There are some issues in processing HDFC test card details shared as sample by payu money. So as an alternative you can use any of the test cards from 
https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm

For Example you can user Amex card:
American Express
378282246310005
User Any name, any CVV, Any Expiry

PayuMoney will redirect you to Amex website. Since its a test card you can choose any of the response you want Amex to send.

Good Luck.

-Anuj

Answer (score 0):

use fake account no from this link

use fake account no from 
https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm

if 5123456789012346 no is not work